# How can I remove website fields from Add User Page in wordpress admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Its getting impossible for me now to remove website field from wordpress dashboard Add User page. Someone please suggest something??

Comment: Do you want to remove menus?

Comment: No i do not want to remove menus, i want to remove website and twitter field dispaly in edit user and add user page.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this can help you:

```
function hide_website_krotedev(){
  echo "\n" . '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(\'label[for=url], input#url\').hide();
  }); 
  </script>' . "\n";
}
add_action('admin_head','hide_website_krotedev');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the Twitter field in the user profile then you should add the following code to your `functions.php` file.

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {


    // Remove profile fields
    unset($profile_fields['twitter']);

    return $profile_fields;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods',10,1);
```

Unfortunately there's no easy way to remove the Website field at this time, you can always hide it with `jQuery` but that's a bit messy of course.

I hope that helps, also check out the stackexchange website for WordPress questions here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: this solution does work for aim, yim and jabber. this doesnt work for googleplus, website and twitter.

Comment: I updated my answer, the answer above remove the twitter field

Answer (score 1):

The User profile Website field [seems to be hard-coded in user-edit.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94963/removing-website-field-from-the-contact-info), so you shouldn't remove it. But you **can** hide it with CSS. Add this code to your functions.php file:

```
function remove_website_row_wpse_94963_css()
{
    echo '<style>tr.user-url-wrap{ display: none; }</style>';
}
add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'remove_website_row_wpse_94963_css' );
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php',   'remove_website_row_wpse_94963_css' );
```

Comment: This only removes the website field from the Edit User page.  It would not remove it from the Add New User page.

Answer (score 1):

I changed kroteDev's answer to instead hide the row rather than the individual fields.

```
function hide_website_field(){
    // Hide the website field on the admin Add New User form
    echo "\n" . '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(\'label[for=url]\').parent().parent().hide();
    }); 
    </script>' . "\n";
}
add_action('admin_head','hide_website_field');
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code can be used to remove the menu's you add to the $restricted array.

```
function remove_menus () {
global $menu;
$restricted = array(__('Dashboard'), __('Posts'), __('Media'), __('Links'), __('Pages'), __('Appearance'), __('Tools'), __('Users'), __('Settings'), __('Comments'), __('Plugins'));
end ($menu);
while (prev($menu)){
    $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
    if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
}
}
  add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

Comment: No i do not want to remove menus, i want to remove website and twitter field dispaly in edit user and add user page

Comment: Downvoted because this is not the answer the OP is looking for.

Answer (score -6):

**go wp-admin/user-edit.php**

> comment this code

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="url"><?php _e('Website') ?></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo esc_attr($profileuser->user_url) ?>" class="regular-text code" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: good answer Ravi, thanks. But can you please help me bit more that how can i do this with my plugin or my functions.php file. is there any way to override it from these files.

Comment: Don't hack the core, ever! Please note that if you do this that your chance will be overwritten when you update your WordPress version (which you should ALWAYS do!)